# If some of the columns of the data set are empty, I want to eliminate that columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I'm using R and stuck at the following problem.
I have a data called `data`. It has 48 columns. `id`, `title_1`, `title_2`, ..., `title_47`. `id` stands for personal id and the other 47 columns include the values either H or L or P or N or "" .  Here I mean `""` as empty.
My goal is to eliminate the columns that have all empty values. Definitely all the values of `id` are filled with number. So I think I should make a `for` sentence for `title_1` to `title_47` to check whether some of them have all empty values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `Filter` the columns which have `all` values "". Here I use an example dataframe where the column title_2 has only "" values:

```
Filter(function(x)!all(x == ""), df)
```

Output:

```
  id title_1
1  1       2
2  2       3
3  3       5
```

#### Data used as an example:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                 title_1 = c(2,3,5),
                 title_2 = c("", "", ""))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, based on `dplyr` (I am using @Quinten's data, to whom I thank):

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(which(colSums(df != "") != 0))

#>   id title_1
#> 1  1       2
#> 2  2       3
#> 3  3       5
```

Comment: Or: `select(where(~ all(. != "")))`

Comment: Thanks, @harre, for having commented my answer. True, that would be a possibility, but when I answered there were already published solutions based on such an idea, and therefore I decided to differentiate!

Answer (score 1):

Data from @Quinten(many thanks). Here is a solution with `sapply`

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                 title_1 = c(2,3,5),
                 title_2 = c("", "", ""))

df[, !sapply(df, function(x) all(x == ""))]
```

```
  id title_1
1  1       2
2  2       3
3  3       5
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also `discard` from `purrr`:

```r
library(purrr)

df |> discard(~ all(. == ""))
```

Output:

```r
  id title_1
1  1       2
2  2       3
3  3       5
```

Data from @Quinten. Thanks.